# Is having my home server connected to wired (via powerline) and wireless network beneficial

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, powerline-networking

I have my router in my hall downstairs and my office with home server upstairs. Unfortunately I can't run any ethernet between the two so they are connected using powerline adaptors.

I am about to get a fancy new AC1900 router that should significantly speed up my wifi access so I was wondering if it would be worth connecting my home server to both the wireless and wired network. Would I see any benefit here?

Would it only use one of the connections or use both? Would it pick the fastest connection?

I am thinking about when I am accessing videos that are stored on the server or browsing photos. Photos can be slow to appear and I just don't do anything with videos on my laptop as it takes too long to copy.

Ideally I'd like the server to use both the powerline adaptor and wifi to get as much bandwidth to the router as possible.

Thanks

Comment: You've answered your own question... it would prefer the fastest connection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use only one connection at a time. Not necessarily the fastest one , it's [a bit more complicated](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/299540/en-us). Probably Wi-Fi will be preferred, even if it's slower or less reliable.

So no, you won't benefit from additional Wi-Fi connection, unless Wi-Fi alone will be faster than powerline adapters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not really what I was hoping for but there we go!